# Access Form Text Field Update

Tags: forms, ms-access

Users have been accessing different forms based on the login credentials mentioned in the code below. Instead of this, I would like all the users to open the same form i.e. `frm_search` where unbound text box i.e. `ZAO_Code`, should display the text typed in the `"USER_NAME"` field of the current form. Also, the user should not be able to change the text updated in `ZAO_Code`.

```
Private Sub Command8_Click()
    Dim stDocName As String
    Dim stLinkCriteria As String
    Dim USER_NAME As String

    LoginID.SetFocus
    USER_NAME = LoginID.Text
    Password.SetFocus
    If USER_NAME = "8902" Then
        If Password.Value = "T12!853G" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8902"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8903" Then
        If Password.Value = "M14!8H3" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8903"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8904" Then
        If Password.Value = "A12#853L" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8904"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8906" Then
        If Password.Value = "J12!8M3" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8906"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8907" Then
        If Password.Value = "K12!93L" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8907"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8908" Then
        If Password.Value = "T99!853G" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8908"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8909" Then
        If Password.Value = "F42!753L" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8909"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8911" Then
        If Password.Value = "N12!#53B" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8911"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If


    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8914" Then
        If Password.Value = "TG12!953T" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8914"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8915" Then
        If Password.Value = "T12!M53Q" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8915"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8917" Then
        If Password.Value = "T22!873E" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8917"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If

    ElseIf USER_NAME = "8918" Then
        If Password.Value = "TG12!953T" Then
            stDocName = "Frm_8918"
        Else: MsgBox "Please Enter Correct Login Credentials"
        End If
    End If
```

Comment: Can you add a tag to indicate the language you're using?

Comment: @Shakti I assume that stDocName is the name of the form which will be opened. Well, can't you just remove all the lines where this is set, and set stDocName to "frm_search" just once?

Comment: @Shakti As for ZAO_Code - can't you set the Locked property?

Comment: @Mark Setting stDocName to "frm_search" shall open up the form at click of command button 8. My requirement is to get the "USER_NAME" that might be one of 8902 or 8903 etc to get auto updated in text box on "frm_search" once user has logged in using the credentials mentioned in the code.

Comment: @Shakti At root, your problems are caused by a horrible design. This is why you have so much code that looks the same, except for username and password. At the least, you should be storing usernames and passwords in the database, which means that you could write a simple SQL statement to match the username and password.